# use enter on keyboard to fire a function ionic3

Tags: ionic2

I want to use the enter keyboard button on my phone to search for items. the red link has the filter function on it that I also want to fire when you press the enter/search button on your mobile device. how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the `(keyup.enter)` to detect a Enter button press.

```
<ion-input type="text" (keyup.enter)="onEnter()"></ion-input>
```

and in your `.ts` file you can handle the event

```
onEnter(){
  //do search
}
```